# Why doesn't passing in an array of Materials to the THREE.Mesh constructor work here?

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I'm new to three.js, I can't quite understand why the array isn't working here. The documentation and several guides suggest to pass in an array to the constructor.

From the [`threejs.org`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Mesh):

> ### Constructor
>
> #### Mesh( geometry : BufferGeometry, material : Material )
>
> ***geometry*** — (optional) an instance of BufferGeometry. Default is a new BufferGeometry.
> ***material*** — (optional) a single or an ***array*** of Material. Default is a new MeshBasicMaterial

I can reference an index of the array and see that the texture loads correctly:

```js
// this works:
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials[4] );

// passing in the array doesn't, why?
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials );
```

I've made a [Codepen here.](https://codepen.io/lysdexic/pen/KKWOdvd) using the same repro posted below:

```js
function make_texture(name)
{
  const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  document.body.appendChild(ctx.canvas);
  ctx.canvas.width = 256; ctx.canvas.height = 256;
  ctx.font = '20pt Arial';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fillRect(5, 5, ctx.canvas.width - 10, ctx.canvas.height - 10);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.fillText(name, ctx.canvas.width / 2, ctx.canvas.height / 2);
  const texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(ctx.canvas);
  return texture
};

var materials = [];
for ( var i = 1; i < 7; i ++ ) {
    materials.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: make_texture(i) } ) );
};

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );

// this works:
// var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials[4] );

// passing in the array doesn't, why?
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials );


scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 3;

var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1.5);
pointLight.position.set(0, 300, 200);

scene.add(pointLight);

var animate = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );

  cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
  cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

  renderer.render( scene, camera );
};

animate();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some further investigation it turns out this was a versioning problem - the revision of `three.js` from the CDN in the template I used on CodePen was `r84` and produces the above behaviour.

Updating the settings in the codepen to to `r128` using the links [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/three.js) solves this problem and works as expected.

Fixed CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/lysdexic/pen/KKWOdvd).